# Sequence dependent on my place and the time

Tags: number-sequence, geography, knowledge

I am on place A, somewhere in the United States of America.

- If I go to the Southwest, my sequence starts as following:

  > 3880181, 967089, 299246, 212635, 194944,  ...
- If I go to the Northwest, my sequence starts as following:

  > 1009518, 483702, 288146, 221846, 133791, ...
- If I go to the Northeast, my sequence starts as following:

  > 588349, 587272, 545089, 529354, 422495, ...
- If I go to the Southeast, my sequence starts as following:

  > 629292, 198791, 142955, 122427, 117866, ...

---

Additional hints:

- Hint 1:

  > Each sequence consists of positive integers and is decreasing.
- Hint 2:

  > Each sequence changes over time, and it probably changes every day.
- Hint 3:

  > The last sequence has 33 elements.

---

Questions:

- Where is point A?
- What do the numbers represent?
- How many elements does the third sequence have?

Comment: I suspected that the numbers were populations of cities, with A being on the intersection of four states. Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: @frodoskywalker You are extremely close. Look for another word with a C. Also, keep in mind that the numbers might be a bit outdated. These numbers are form June 2007.

Comment: Searching "3880181 population" is an instant giveaway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I deserve any credit for this answer, since I found it thanks to the massive additional hint from user [f''](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12408/f).
Anyway, here is the correct answer, I think :

Point A is

> somewhere in the Four Corners region, where boundaries of four U.S. states meet: Arizona (SW, first sequence), Utah (NW, second sequence), Colorado (NE, third sequence) and New Mexico.

The numbers represent

> county population, in descending order, for each of the four states.

Therefore, Sequence 1 translates to

> Maricopa, Pima, Pinal, Yavapai, Mohave (or Yuma, I couldn't find 2007 source data, can't access to census.gov for some reason), ...

Sequence 2 translates to

> Salt Lake, Utah, Davis, Weber, Washington, ...

Sequence 3 translates to

> Denver, El Paso (which is now the most populated county, it seems), Arapahoe, Jefferson, Adams, ...

Sequence 4 translates to

> Bernalillo, Doña Ama, Santa Fe, Sandoval, San Juan, ...

The third sequence has

> 64 elements (Colorado has 64 counties in total).